# CSS3 Тень объекта

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, hover

Подскажите, как сделать что бы при наведении мышкой на кнопку, тень появлялась на кругу, по отдельности получается, вместе нет.

```css
.roll{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    border: solid 5px red;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
} 
.roll:hover{
    box-shadow: 0 30px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.bat{
    width: 100px;
    height: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}
.bat:hover{
    box-shadow: 0 30px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
```

```html
<div class="roll"></div>
<input  type="button" value="Тык" class="bat" >
```

Comment: Через JS/jQuery.

Comment: Эх... попробую через js

Comment: как вариант можно их поменять местами в коде, сделать `.bat:hover+.roll{...}` а порядок отображения поменять обратно через `flex-direction:column-reverse`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для динамического связывания элементов, работы с поведением и событиями в веб-разработке принято использовать [JavaScript](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript). Для того, чтобы избежать рутины при выполнении стандартных операций на DOM, используют фреймворки и библиотеки. В данном случае используется [jQuery](https://github.com/jquery/jquery).

### upd.

Можно влиять на соседние элементы через [комбинаторы селекторов](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_%D0%A1%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B) `+` или `~`, но элементы, в таком случае, должны располагаться под (следовать за) hover-элементом. Как указывали в комментариях, [можно использовать](http://the-echoplex.net/flexyboxes/) `flexbox` для изменения порядка следования элементов. Можно изменять позиционирование `position`. В примере "немного кривовато" показано, как элементы поменяны местами через `position`.

```js
// событие 
$('.bat').hover(function(){
   // добавление/удаление класса hover
   $('.roll').toggleClass('hover')
})
```

```css
.roll{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    border: solid 5px red;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    transition: all .2s;
} 
.roll:hover{
    box-shadow: 0 30px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.bat{
    width: 100px;
    height: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}
.bat:hover{
    box-shadow: 0 30px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

/* определение стиля при наведении */
.roll.hover {
  border-color: blue;
  box-shadow: 0 30px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  transform: scale(1.05);
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

#one {
 padding: .2rem;
 border:1px solid #fff;
 position: absolute;
 border-radius: 4px;
}

#one:hover {
  background: #f5f5f5;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#two {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 64px;
  display: block;
  border-radius: 100%;
  border: 1px solid green;
  width: 48px;
  height: 48px;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all .2s;
}

#one:hover + #two {
  background: yellow;
  transform: translateY(-5px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="roll"></div>
<input  type="button" value="Тык" class="bat" >

<br><br><br>

<div class="wrapper">
  <a id="one">a'm one</a>
  <a id="two">a'm two</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо!!!
Стало интересно, а как это можно сделать, не используя  jQuery, может знаете?)

Comment: + вариант с flexbox https://codepen.io/diproart/pen/qyNgww

Comment: Супер!! Разобрался, большое спасибо!!